# Can't run STS after change to Java 7 version

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

I was following this instruction and set my STS environment to use Java 7, instead of Java 8 [HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet fitTrackerServlet threw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416540/http-status-500-servlet-init-for-servlet-fittrackerservlet-threw-exception)

And now when I want to run STS, I get this error message:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Can I somehow resolve this situation or I must install new STS ?

Comment: Try to edit the file sts.ini (it is along the executable), and change the required Java version

Comment: I tried...it was set to 1.7 version, I changed it to 1.8, and still not working

Comment: the latest versions of STS require a JDK8 to run, so a JDK7 won't be enough, even if you modify the STS.ini file to accept a JDK7 for startup. Features will be missing and disabled due to JDK8 requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages look like you doesn't have specified the JDK to run STS in a way that the Eclipse launcher like it. Here is a detailed explanation of how to specify the JDK to run Eclipse/STS:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Keep in mind that STS has a STS.ini file instead of an eclipse.ini file, but everything else applies to the STS.ini file, too. And keep in mind that the -vm param has to be the first one in that file, followed by an additional line with the path to the java executable.

Comment: I did some changes, and now I can launch it...this is how my sts.ini looks like: 

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m

Comment: If you are running a recent STS version that ships with the -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8, I can't recommend to modify that to run it with a JDK7 instead. Several features will disappear, other things might not work at all. You should be able to do the same for a JDK8, but keep in mind to put the lines "-vm" and "C:\Program..." as the first lines in your ini file.